# Reverse Queue without using stack

Tags: python, python-3.x, queue, reverse

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.next = None

    def __str__(self):
        return "Node({})".format(self.value)

    __repr__ = __str__

class Queue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head=None
        self.tail=None

    def __str__(self):
        temp=self.head
        out=[]
        while temp:
            out.append(str(temp.value))
            temp=temp.next
        out=' '.join(out)
        return ('Head:{}\nTail:{}\nQueue:{}'.format(self.head,self.tail,out))

    __repr__=__str__

    def isEmpty(self):
        #write your code here
        return (self.head == None) and (self.tail == None)
    def __len__(self):
        #write your code here
        current = self.head
        len = 0
        while current:
            len += 1
            current = self.head.next
            if self.head.next == self.tail:
                break
        return len

    def enqueue(self, value):
        #write your code here
        node = Node(value)
        if self.isEmpty():
            self.head = node
            self.tail = node
        else:
            self.tail.next = node
            self.tail = node

    def dequeue(self):
        #write your code here
        if self.isEmpty():
            return 'Queue is empty'
        else:
            popped = self.head.value
            self.head = self.head.next
            return popped

    def front(self):
        if self.head != None:

            return self.head.value

q = Queue()
def reversequeue(q):
    if q.isEmpty() == False:        
        data = q.front()
        q.dequeue()
        reversequeue(q)
        q.enqueue(data)
def QueuePalindrome(word):
    q = Queue()
    for i in word:
        q.enqueue(i)

    p = reversequeue(q)
    return p
```

The function reversequeue returns "Nonetype" object has no attribute value. Im not sure how to proceed with this.

When I test q.front(). It returns the correct answer. I try to catch the error by stating that if the self.head == None then skip it.

What should I do in this situation?

Please help. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function `reversequeue(q)` has no `return` statement

```
def reversequeue(q):
    if q.isEmpty() == False:        
        data = q.front()
        q.dequeue()
        reversequeue(q)
        q.enqueue(data)
```

thus it defaults to returning `None`. Just add a return for the base case, and for the recursive case, and update `q`:

```
def reversequeue(q):
    if q.isEmpty() == False:        
        data = q.front()
        q.dequeue()
        q = reversequeue(q)
        q.enqueue(data)
        return q
    return Queue()
```

Comment: the problem is the function return q.front() is a NoneType